# "An error occurred while parsing EntityName" while Loading an XmlDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have written some code to parse RSS feeds for a ASP.NET C# application and it works fine for all RSS feeds that I have tried, until I tried Facebook.

My code fails at the last line below...

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream rss = response.GetResponseStream();
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(rss);
```

...with the error "An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 12, position 53."

It is hard to work out what is at thhat position of the XML file as the entire file is all in one line, but it is straight from Facebook and all characters appear to be encoded properly except possibly one character (♥).

I don't particularly want to rewrite my RSS parser to use a different method. Any suggestions for how to bypass this error? Is there a way of turning off checking of the file?

Comment: Is a character set definition required? I've had XML files (not RSS) that didn't work until I added a character set definition to the top of the file. Though if you're receiving this should it not already have one?! Maybe you can post the data.

Comment: An example RSS feed is https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=155774311113436&format=rss20

Comment: Looks like it has an encoding then! No use to you but yes I get an error in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the downloaded stream. It doesn't contain the RSS feed, but a HTML page with message about incompatible browser. That's because when downloading the URL like this, [the user agent header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) is not set. If you do that, your code should work:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "MyApplication";

var xml = new XmlDocument();

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var rss = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    xml.Load(rss);
}
```